# Override implicit vals from trait

Tags: scala

I need overriding implicit in object *res* defing one from trait. The purpose is to define custom implicits in one place (*trait B*). *Trait a* is defined in external library. Is it possible?

```
trait t {
}

object m extends t
object q extends t

trait a {
  implicit val o: t = m
}

trait b {
  implicit val o: t = q
}

trait c {
  def action(implicit v: t): Unit  = {} 
}

object res extends c with a with b {
  //i need smth like override val o = super[b].o
  val ololo= action
}
```

Comment: I found http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/12ak3cacsm/how-do-i-override-and-select-a-base-method-from-two-conflicting-traits which ended up linking to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1938

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to mix-in two unrelated traits that both contain a member with the same identifier. The Scala compiler has no way to resolve which one would take precedence in this scenario. Since types `A` and `B` are related, `o` does not even need to have the same type in both of them. Trait `B` needs to extend `A` and override `o`. There isn't any other way to override a member without using inheritance.

```
trait T
case object M extends T
case object Q extends T

trait A {
  implicit val o: T = M
}

trait B extends A {
  override implicit val o: T = Q
}

trait C {
  def action(implicit v: T): Unit = println(v)
}

object Res extends C with B {
    def call() = action
}

scala> Res.call()
Q
```

Since you are already mixing `A` into `Res` *anyway*, it is assumed that `A` is not difficult to extend, since `Res` must implement any other unmentioned abstract members.